# How to configure /etc/resolv.conf in my kube-flannel-ds pods of a k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, nameserver

I'm running a kubernetes cluster (bare metal; v1.23) with one master and three workers. I'm using flannel (v0.19.2) for pod network.

In my syslog I see errors like: `Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is: 46.38.252.230 46.38.225.230 2a03:4000:8000::fce6`, which has its origin in the `kube-flannel-ds` pods.
Inside of the pods I see:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 46.38.252.230
nameserver 46.38.225.230
nameserver 2a03:4000:0:1::e1e6
search
```

As there are more than three lines, the error message occurs. But I am not sure, how to solve this as I do not know how this conf file is generated.

On k8s cluster creation I did: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.19.2/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml >> pod_network_setup.txt`

---

*Update*

The worker nodes are running on a ubuntu 22.04 machine.

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

**resolvectl status**

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 46.38.252.230
       DNS Servers: 46.38.252.230 46.38.225.230 2a03:4000:8000::fce6 2a03:4000:0:1::e1e6

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Answer (score 0):

If `dnsPolicy` is set to `Default`, Kubernetes pods inherit DNS configuration from the worker nodes they're on.

Depending on your worker Linux distribution and other details, you may find that configuration in:

- /etc/resolv.conf
- /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
- /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ (Fedora, Centos and RHEL)

Comment: I've updated the post with some more infos

Comment: FYI, RHEL 9 finally abandoned `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` in favor of NetworkManager.